# libcurl version 7.21 to work on Redhat 6

Tags: linux, curl, c

I am having an issue with libcurl version 7.19 and socks proxy on redhat 6.  I believe it was fixed in libcurl version 7.21 how do i upgrade libcurl on redhat 6 to 7.21 or greater?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this repo: http://mirror.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/sysutils/Mirroring/

(Which is listed on the official website of curl: https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)